# how to show a custom taxonomy as dropdown in wordpress?

Tags: menus

I want to show a custom taxonomy in the name of custom_tax in a plugin option page as dropdown that user can select terms of taxonomy.
I know that I can use [wp_dropdown_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) but I don't want show the terms of category taxonomy. I'm going to show my custom taxonomy terms as dropdown.
Is there any function to do that? or no how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) has the `taxonomy` parameter, which defaults to `category`, but can be used to retrieve custom taxonomies. Exemplary usage:

```
wp_dropdown_categories([
  'taxonomy' => 'custom-taxonomy-name'
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

[get_terms() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
should help you. An example:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'custom_tax',
) );
```